# Anything to know before selling a Lease back to the freeholder

Tags: real-estate, real-estate-leasing

We're about to sell our leasehold, ex-council property back to the council, i.e. back to the freeholder of the lease.

Is there anything we should know about beforehand?

Should we expect this to be easier, or harder, than a normal sale?
Should we be asking our conveyancer to decrease their price, or be expecting them to warn of increased costs?

Comment: How much time is left on your lease ?

Comment: @DumbCoder 90+ years. 92, I think. Why do you ask?